# Ignite service hangs when call cache remove in another cache's invoke processor, " Possible starvation in striped pool"?

Tags: ignite

Ignite logs have starvation waringings and stop to provide service:

```
[12:55:22,080][WARNING][grid-timeout-worker-#71][G] >>> Possible starvation in striped pool.
    Thread name: sys-stripe-25-#26
    Deadlock: false
    Completed: 16272032
Thread [name="sys-stripe-25-#26", id=51, state=WAITING, blockCnt=79, waitCnt=15616666]
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:304)
    at o.a.i.i.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:177)
    at o.a.i.i.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:140)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.remove0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:716)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.remove(GridCacheAdapter.java:3084)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.remove(GridCacheAdapter.java:3065)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.remove(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1131)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.remove(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:998)
    at com.test.info.TestInfoBasicExecutor.handleCurrentLevel(TestInfoBasicExecutor.java:281)
    at com.test.info.TestInfoBasicExecutor$infoEntryProcessor.process(TestInfoBasicExecutor.java:514)
    at com.test.info.TestInfoBasicExecutor$infoEntryProcessor.process(TestInfoBasicExecutor.java:453)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry$AtomicCacheUpdateClosure.runEntryProcessor(GridCacheMapEntry.java:5142)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry$AtomicCacheUpdateClosure.call(GridCacheMapEntry.java:4550)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry$AtomicCacheUpdateClosure.call(GridCacheMapEntry.java:4367)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$Invoke.invokeClosure(BPlusTree.java:3051)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$Invoke.access$6200(BPlusTree.java:2945)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.invokeDown(BPlusTree.java:1717)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.invoke(BPlusTree.java:1600)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.invoke(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:1199)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheOffheapManager$GridCacheDataStore.invoke(GridCacheOffheapManager.java:1357)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.invoke(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:345)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.innerUpdate(GridCacheMapEntry.java:1767)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateSingle(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2420)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.update(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1883)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1736)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1628)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.processNearAtomicUpdateRequest(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:3055)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$400(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:130)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$5.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:266)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$5.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:261)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1060)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:579)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:378)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:304)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:99)
    at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:293)
    at o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1555)
    at o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1183)
    at o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:126)
    at o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1090)
    at o.a.i.i.util.StripedExecutor$Stripe.run(StripedExecutor.java:505)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I use invoke to update Cache A, and in the etnryprocessor of cache A,
I konw the processor is already invoked wiht a lock, and i just doing update for another cacher base this entry,
I have checked the value of Cache A, and based on the value, do update to cache B entries, i.e. put or remove, in my test,
put is ok, but for remove it seems the remove cause service hangs:

```
    at com.test.info.TestInfoBasicExecutor.handleCurrentLevel(TestInfoBasicExecutor.java:281)
    at com.test.info.TestInfoBasicExecutor$infoEntryProcessor.process(TestInfoBasicExecutor.java:514)
    at com.test.info.TestInfoBasicExecutor$infoEntryProcessor.process(TestInfoBasicExecutor.java:453)
```

## ======================================================

Update 0702:

To prevent the starvation, i changed my code:

In Ignite Service A's excute function:

cacheA.invoke(record){
// do process to record

igniteQueue.put(processed_record);

}

In Ignite Service B's excute function:

saved_processed_record = igniteQueue.take();

=================

I have try to use this way to prevent the starvation, It runs smoothly when
the old code with starvation(TPS is low), but when i running with high TPS,
the "Possible starvation in striped pool" back again,

It seems I use igniteQueue in cache.invoke is also not correct vs. previous cache in cache.invoke

When i want is do process for each record in cache, and then base the processed record to update other caches, but it seems it's not possilbe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid doing cache operations within the entry processor, even if those operations belong to other caches. The reason for that is that all these operations will use the same thread pool - this can cause starvation.

Comment: thank for you answer, Is there any suggestion of how to doing this  kind of updata a cache's entry which depand on another cache's entry, i have try to change the update to cache B in my post to record the entry to another ignite queue, and lauch a service check the queue with take() method and base this to update ignite cache B, and it works for now, but i want to know does this approach could avoid the thread starvation or not?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "depends" here? What kind of consistency/atomicity guarantees are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have update my post to make my issue more clear, please check the update in the original post --0702 update, thanks.

Comment: `IgniteQueue` uses Ignite cache under the hood, so the cause of `Possible starvation in striped pool` is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Striped pool used for processing of the Ignite messages. Looks like for some reason all the threads from this pool is waiting for some operation (remove from cache in your log). It could be related to network problems or removing takes a lot of time (for example you are going to remove all the data).

Could you please attach the thread dump and your test code for investigation?

Comment: I have 3 there and 5 client, the client get cache info from client, i don't know if this issue related with too much clients to retrive the same cache, for the backtrace, the server could not be dumped it give error, so i just dump the thread backtrace for client, and paste it here: https://pastebin.com/R2bpbimu